# Terraform - Azure: Variables append

Tags: azure, terraform

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "HVTest1" {
  location = "${var.location}"
  name = "HVTest1.RG"
}


resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic"{

  name = "TestLinux-nic${count.index}"
  location = "${var.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.HVTest1.name}"
  ip_configuration{
   name = "test-ipconfig"
   subnet_id = "${var.subnet_id}"
   private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
   #public_ip_address_id = "None"
  }
  count = 2
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "TestRHEL" {

    count = "${var.count}"
    location = "${var.location}"
    resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.HVTest1.name}"
    #name = "TestRHEL-${count.index}"
    name = "TestRHEL-${count.index}"
    vm_size = "Standard_DS1_v2"
    network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.nic.*.id[count.index]}"]
    delete_os_disk_on_termination = true
    delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

    storage_image_reference {
        publisher = "Canonical"
        offer = "Ubuntuserver"
        sku = "16.04-LTS"
        version = "latest"
    }


    storage_os_disk {
        #name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.TestLVM.*.name}-osdisk"
        name = "TestRHELosdisk-${format(var.count_format, var.count_offset + count.index +1)}"
        caching = "None"
        create_option = "FromImage"
        managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    }

    os_profile {

        computer_name = "TestRHEL-${count.index}"
        admin_username = "venihe01"
        admin_password = "Nielsen@1234"
    }

    storage_data_disk {
        name = "${TestRHEL-${count.index}-data1}"
        managed_disk_type = "standard_LRS"
        create_option = "Empty"
        lun = "${count.index}"
        disk_size_gb = "100"
        count = 2

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have counts in `storage_data_disk` they can only be in top level resources.

You can do multiple `storage_data_disk` in a resource like

```
 resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "TestRHEL" {
    storage_data_disk {
      name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.TestLVM.name}-data0"
      managed_disk_type = "standard_LRS"
      create_option = "Empty"
      lun = "0"
      disk_size_gb = "100"
    }
    storage_data_disk {
      name = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.TestLVM.name}-data1"
      managed_disk_type = "standard_LRS"
      create_option = "Empty"
      lun = "1"
      disk_size_gb = "100"
    }
 }
```

Comment: As the storage accounts per server will be changed based on the application, how can we automate this process as part of server setup? Also, after modifying the code with above suggestion getting below error.

* azurerm_virtual_machine.TestRHEL[0]: azurerm_virtual_machine.TestRHEL[0]: self reference not allowed: "azurerm_virtual_machine.TestRHEL.name"

Comment: generally you don'e reference the name of the VM in there you just add it there

Comment: `name = "TestRHEL-${count.index}-data1"` for the storage_data_disk

Comment: storage_data_disk {
  count = 2
  name = "TestRHEL-${count.index}-data1"
  managed_disk_type = "standard_LRS"
  create_option = "Empty"
  lun = 0
  disk_size_gb = "100"
  
 }


Getting below error.

2 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_virtual_machine.TestRHEL[0]: storage_data_disk.0: invalid or unknown key: count
* azurerm_virtual_machine.TestRHEL[1]: storage_data_disk.0: invalid or unknown key: count

Comment: you'd have to re-post your whole config in like a pastebin or gist

Comment: Updated the my original post with the latest config

Comment: this is wrong `name = "${TestRHEL-${count.index}-data1}"`  it should be `name = "TestRHEL-${count.index}-data1"`

Comment: plus you still have the count in `storage_data_disk` you can't do that